# Given an array, how can I index match each value and sum them without a helper column?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have multiple rows 34 columns wide with a reference Designator(RefDes) in each one that correlates to a value. I am trying to find a way to match each RefDes to its value and sum those together without the use of a helper cell for each column to give each row a total value.

My current formula will work with a helper cell but that adds 34 more columns and makes it very messy and hard to read.

```
=INDEX(FullFlow2[[Category Times]:[Category Times]],MATCH(N4,FullFlow2[[REFDES]:[REFDES]]))
```

Followed by a `=sumproduct()`in another column to collect the values.

Not sure if this is something I will need to use VBA for or if I can make it work without it.

This is the RefDesTable below
[image: RefDesTable]

This is the FullFlow2 Table below

[image: FullFlow2Table]

Comment: Please provide a visual representation of the data and expected output.  It makes it easier to understand the question.

Comment: Pictures have been added, thank you! New user learning how to ask questions better so I appreciate the guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS wrapped in a SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(FullFlow2[[Category Times]:[Category Times]],FullFlow2[[REFDES]:[REFDES]],YourFirstTableName[1st]))
```

Replace `YourFirstTableName` with the correct name for the table.

Comment: Ahh,  You wanted by row, I assumed column.  Good job changing to your need.

Comment: Got it work perfectly! Thank you, needed to go across the row though so I changed that a bit. Here is what I ended up using. 

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(FullFlow2[[Category Times]:[Category Times]],FullFlow2[[REFDES]:[REFDES]],FullSNList__FBD[@[1st]:[34th]]))`

Thank you for your help.